# What are the different Work Items in Team Foundation Server used for?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, project-management

Please read this entire question before you try to mark this as "too controversial". I am actually setting up my Project Management/Bug Tracking environment with Team Foundation Server for the first time(I have used JIRA,Mantis and some other PM software before). I am fairly knew to using team foundation to anything else besides source control.

I am really trying to use the Work Items for what they were intended to be used for. Having said that, I want to make sure that when I am adding new work items, I am classifying them correctly.

When I choose to add a work Item, If have the following options to select from:

1)Bug
2)Issue
3)Shared Step
4)Task
5)Test Case
6)User Story

Obviously I am aware of what classifies a bug, this is not what is confusing me. What I would really like to know is, what classifies an issue? What technically classifies a Task? What is a user story? etc.

I know there may be some opinion in this, but I am really trying to organize the project, and separate all of these correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506503/tfs-work-item-types-tasks-vs-scenarios-or-use-both) question talks about some of the stuff you've mentioned here

Answer (score 0):

You can find the MSF Agile 5.0 process template guidance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380647%28VS.100%29.aspx).  When you create a team project you should receive an option, after it's complete to read the process guidance.  This is what that will take you too if you choose MSF Agile 5.0.  Also take a look at the [VS Scrum Process Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e/).  It's very simple and as true to Scrum as any tool or process guidance.  It was shipped out-of-band, but will be included in the next version of TFS (if not SP1).